# C++ Char Array Find / Replace a char

Tags: c++, arrays, replace, find

So basically I have an array which looks like this:

```
char array[25];
```

I have an 'X' put in there, and 24 'O's. I am trying to create a function where I can find the location of 'X' in the array, so then I can move it whenever a control is typed in. Here is some code to get an idea on what I am thinking, I just can't put it together.

```
int findX(){
    //make this find the location of X out of the 25 char array.
    //then return the slot of X as a number, like if it's in the 20th slot, then  it will return 20 ?
    //return(locationOfX);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you need [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)? Because it should teach you all you need to know to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Use std::string!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 'X')
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

This should do it, I had no chance testing it, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the array and the number of elements.
1. The *manual* approach:

```
int findX(char arr[], int count){
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if (arr[i] == 'X'){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

2. Use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function:

```
int findX2(char arr[], int count){
    return std::find(arr, arr + count, 'X') - arr;
}
```

Slight twist with the [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) function:

```
int findX2(char arr[], int count){
    return std::distance(arr, std::find(arr, arr + count, 'X'));
}
```

3. Pass in the beginning and the end of the array:

```
int findX3(char* arrbegin, char* arrend){
    return std::distance(arrbegin, std::find(arrbegin, arrend, 'X'));
}
```

and use like:

```
std::cout << findX3(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

4. Template function left as an exercise.
That being said, **prefer** [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to raw arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ron's answer is more correct because actually I think in C there isn't a function like "XXX.length()", so you need to pass the length of the array to the function.

Comment: While I appreciate the feedback I would like to point out that comments should be posted as comments, not as answers. Please build up some reps to be able to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

In language C you can use `strstr` function.

```
#include "string.h"
int findX(char array[])
{
   char *result = strstr(array, "s");
   return result - array;
}
int main()
{
   char array[25];
   int index = findX(array);
}
```

in C++ use `std::find()` or just change `array` to `std::string` and use `string::find`

here is the code:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string array = "oooooooooosoooooooooooooo";
    int index = array.find("s");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strstr requires that the argument is a string. OP's array is not null terminated and therefore is not a string.